# UWP ask for user location again

Tags: uwp

I have an UWP app that ask user location when load some datas on main page, it dislay the dialog box once : on the first launch.

My question is : if the user refuses the location and later wishes to activate it, how do i re-show the dialog box ?

Note : for ask location i use :

```
var access = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to use this code again and again if the user doesnt grant access. You just need to check for status.

```
if (access == GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed)
    access = await Geolocation.RequestAccessAsync();
```

I'm pretty sure you've tried this way and it didn't probably work, yeah? If so, why?